# Xamarin Google Play Services missing?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to get Google Cloud Messaging working in a Xamarin Forms Android app from within Visual Studio 2012 and the `GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)` call is returning error code 1 (Missing Service). I made sure that the NuGet package was installed (otherwise the namespace isn't available) and that the Android SDK Manager had Google Play services installed.

What more do I need to do to make the service available?

**Edit 10/20 1:34PM**

The `IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` returns the success code when I debug the app over USB on my device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I was trying to use the emulators that come with the Android SDK, instead of the Xamarin Android Player https://xamarin.com/android-player.

Keep in mind that you will also need to install the Google Play Store app and update it if you need to use Google Play services https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator

Comment: @John Russo I'm also facing the same issue. I'm getting a MissingMethodException in Xamarin. I'm using a device but still getting the same exception. Could you please let me know how I can resolve this?

Comment: @IngridCooper Did you make sure Google Play updated? (step 8 of the Xamarin University link)

Comment: @John Russo Yes, I checked both Google Play Store and Google Play Services. My Google Play Store version is 5.10.30 and Google Play Services is 8.3.01